# Getting All Classes from A Beautiful Soup Object that Contain a Class Name but not ID

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

```
main_url = 'https://www.indeed.com'
url_to_list = ["https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data%20Scientist&advn=9634682979760233"]

for tab_number in range(1,101):
    url_temp = f'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data+Scientist&start={tab_number}0'
    url_to_list.append(url_temp)

url = url_to_list[0]
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
#class_titles = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "title"}) #Contains Descrition URL and Title 
#class_sjcl = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "sjcl"}) #contains Ratings, company name, area
#class_salarySnippet_holisticSalar = soup.findAll("div",{"class": "salarySnippet holisticSalary"}) #contains pay
main_class = soup.findAll('div', class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard')
```

This is supposed to webscrape Indeed but I got stuck. I want this to give me a Title, description etc. The hard part is that I want it to return None if there is no salary available for example. Everything is contained in `class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard'`

However it has a different ID in each container, so the `findAll()` method returns empty. I've been trying a bunch of other solutions to similar problems but it keeps returning an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will go through the pages and get some information about each result. If the result doesn't have, for example, salary - it will put `'-'` into the data (you can change it to `None` if you want):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data+Scientist&start={}'

data = []
for p in range(0, 100, 10):
    print('Scraping results {}...'.format(p))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url.format(p)).content, 'html.parser')

    for result in soup.select('.result'):
        title = result.select_one('.title').get_text(strip=True)
        job_url = result.select_one('.title a')['href']
        company = result.select_one('.company').get_text(strip=True) if result.select_one('.company') else '-'
        rating = result.select_one('.ratingsDisplay').get_text(strip=True) if result.select_one('.ratingsDisplay') else '-'
        location = result.select_one('.location').get_text(strip=True) if result.select_one('.location') else '-'
        salary = result.select_one('.salary').get_text(strip=True) if result.select_one('.salary') else '-'

        data.append((title, company, rating, location, salary, job_url))

# just print the data for now:    
print('{:<65} {:<50} {:<10} {:<65} {:<10}'.format(*'Title Company Rating Location Salary'.split()))
for row in data:
    print('{:<65} {:<50} {:<10} {:<65} {:<10}'.format(*row[:-1]))
```

Prints:

```
Scraping results 0...
Scraping results 10...
Scraping results 20...
...

Title                                                             Company                                            Rating     Location                                                          Salary    
Data Scientist – Pricing Optimization                             Delta                                              4.2        Atlanta, GA                                                       -         
Data Scientist - Entry Level                                      Numerdox                                           -          Sacramento, CA                                                    -         
Data Scientist                                                    RTI International                                  3.7        Durham, NC 27709                                                  -         
Entry Level Data Scientist                                        IBM                                                3.9        United States                                                     -         
Data Scientist - Economic Data                                    Zillow                                             3.8        Seattle, WA 98101(Downtown area)                                  -         
Data Scientist                                                    FCA                                                4.0        Detroit, MI 48201                                                 -         
Data Scientist, Analytics (University Grad)                       Facebook                                           4.2        New York, NY 10017                                                -         
Data Scientist                                                    Oath Inc                                           3.8        Champaign, IL                                                     -         
...and so on.
```

Comment: @JuanRamos You can use `result` variable the same as `soup` variable - using `find_all`, `select` and other methods... You can look for more examples in [BeautifulSoup doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Could you have used `.row` in the select method?

Comment: @JuanRamos Yes, when I look how the page is structured, you could use `.row` instead `.result` in `select()` method.